# Video streaming through Publish/Subscribe: Which video encoding supports live streaming in C# and HTML 5?

Tags: c#, html, video, apache-kafka, nancy

Busy with a showcase / test of publishing webcam video through Apache Kafka to a Web (NancyFX C#) client in HTML 5. I know the resulting video stream will always have a few seconds lag. But I want to make the solution as fast as possible using newest web (HTML 5), streaming (Kafka), and video(Webm?) technology.

The Kafka part, both Producer and Consumer, are working: Sending Video Frame by Frame in JPeg format(C# System.Drawing.Bitmap) using the http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/. And I can use this library to create a Video File on disk but no streams.

When I use this Webm(VP9) Video File serving it through Nancy as Partial HTTP content (Thank you: http://richardssoftware.net/Home/Post/61) it works oke in the browser. This works fine because you know the total (file)length up front.

But now streaming the Jpeg Frame images on the fly to a Video player in HTML 5 seems not so easy.

My questions:

- Does the HTML 5 Video players support streaming video: So video without an defined endpoint?
- Which Video encoding is best for Live Streaming? I'm currently testing WebM(VP9) but have no experience with Live Video streaming.
- Partial HTTP Content, using NancyFX, seems to support the video time slider offset. But is it also usable for Live video streaming? Maybe using the Kafka offset 1 on 1 or Frame id/key as slider value?

My code so far:

Kafka producer in C# using AForge.net lib to capture video cam:

```
class Program
{
    const string brokerList = "127.0.0.1:2181";
    const string topicName = "video_test";

    static IDictionary<string, object> config = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"bootstrap.servers", "notebook039:9092" },
        {"retries", 0 },
        {"client.id", 200677},
        {"batch.num.messages", 1},
        {"socket.blocking.max.ms", 1},
        {"socket.nagle.disable", true},
        {"queue.buffering.max.ms", 0},
        {"default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"acks", 1}
            }
        }
    };

    static Lazy<Producer<long, Bitmap>> publisher = 
        new Lazy<Producer<long, Bitmap>>(() => new Producer<long, Bitmap>(
                        config, 
                        new LongSerializer(), 
                        new BitmapSerializer()), true);

    static long frameId = 0;

    static private async void video_NewFrame(
                                            object sender,
                                            NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            // get new frame
            Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

            // process the frame
            publisher.Value.ProduceAsync(topicName, ++frameId, bitmap, null);

            if ((frameId % 24 == 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"frameId: {frameId}");
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var cancelled = false;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
                cancelled = true;
        };

        // enumerate video devices
        var videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(
                        FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

        // create video source
        VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(
                        videoDevices[0].MonikerString);

        // set NewFrame event handler
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

        // start the video source
        videoSource.Start();

        while (!cancelled)
        {
            Console.Write("> ");

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }

        // signal to stop
        videoSource.SignalToStop();
    }
}
```

And the C# Nancy Module subscribing to Kafka video Topic:

```
public class KafkaCam : NancyModule
{
    const string brokerList = "notebook039:2181";
    const string topicName = "video_test";

    static IDictionary<string, object> config = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"group.id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
        { "auto.offset.reset", "latest" },
        { "bootstrap.servers", "notebook039:9092" },
        {"retries", 0 },
        {"client.id", 210677},
        {"batch.num.messages", 1},
        {"socket.blocking.max.ms", 1},
        {"socket.nagle.disable", true},
        {"queue.buffering.max.ms", 0},
        {"default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"acks", 1}
            }
        }
    };

    static Lazy<Consumer<long, Bitmap>> subscriber =
    new Lazy<Consumer<long, Bitmap>>(
        () => new Consumer<long, Bitmap>(
                            config,
                            new LongDeserializer(),
                            new BitmapDeserializer()),
        true);


    const string videoFilePath = @"D:\Kafka\clients\KafkaPublishSubscribeTests\data\video.webm";

    Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter videoFile = new Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter();


    public void FramesWriter()
    {
        try
        {
            Message<long, Bitmap> message = null;
            subscriber.Value.Subscribe(topicName);

            if (!videoFile.IsOpen)
            {
                videoFile.Open(videoFilePath, 640, 480, 24, Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoCodec.VP9);
            }

            do
            {
                subscriber.Value.Poll(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

                if (subscriber.Value.Consume(out message, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)) 
                        && message != null )
                {
                    videoFile.WriteVideoFrame(message.Value, (uint)message.Key);
                    videoFile.Flush();
                }
            }
            while (true);

        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            videoFile.Close();
            videoFile = null;
        }
    }


    public KafkaCam()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(FramesWriter);

        Get["/Camera.webm"] = parameters =>
        {
            return Response.FromPartialFile(Request, videoFilePath, "video/webm");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: _"streaming the Jpeg Frame images"_ ... if you have jpegs can't they just  display in `<image>` tag and update image via timer (viewer sees moving video but really it's a sequence (slideshow) of jpegs). For real browser streaming look into HLS format and fragmented MP4s etc..

Comment: I have got the jpeg approach working using <image> tags but the solution took too much cpu for higher resolutions. The current methods i know for your usecase is using HLS, DASH and WebRTC. As you target C#, medialooks MFormats API could make your life easy